# Input submit button and enter

Tags: jquery, input, submit, enter

I have a lot of forms that are submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="image">` or the enter key.

The code used is:

```
<input width="62" type="image" height="22" border="0" onclick="flipSearchButton()" alt="Search" tabindex="9" src="/images/button-search.gif">
```

These forms have now been redeveloped and the code looks like this

```
<a onclick="javascript:flipSearchButton();" class="button blue right" tabindex="9" href="javascript: submitform(&quot;main&quot;)">Search</a>
```

However, since the change, while clicking the enter key does not submit the form.

How can I make the enter button to submit the form?

The html section of the input and clear buttons of the form is:

```
  <div class="inline">
         <a class="icon blue left" onClick="javascript:resetForm();">Clear</a>
    </div>
    <div id="search_clickable">
          <a tabindex="14" class="button blue right" href="javascript:flipSearchButton();submitform('main')">Search</a>
    </div>
    <div id="search_unclickable" class="disp_none;">
          <a class="button blue right" href="">Searching...</a>
     </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetForm() {
        var formObj = document.main;
        formObj.subCategory.value = '';
        formObj.surname.value = '';
        formObj.includeSurnameVariants.checked = false;
        formObj.forenames.value = '';
        formObj.forenames.focus();
        formObj.includeForenamesVariants.checked = true;
        formObj.eventYear.value = '';
        formObj.eventYearTolerance[3].selected = true;              
        formObj.county.value = '';
    }   

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.main.forenames.focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what sort of error do you see in firebug

Comment: I do not see any error. Nothing happens if I click the enter key

Comment: It would help if you provided more of your code so we could look at those functions and see if they are causing your problem.

Comment: When a form has a single input field, hitting `enter` in this field forces a submit - im guess that removing the `input` and replacing it with an `a` has removed this functionality

Comment: I think I will reverse back to the input fields and use a styled version. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a class="button blue right" tabindex="9" 
    href="javascript:flipSearchButton();submitform('main')">Search</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.submitme').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
         submitform('main');
      }
});
```

Add this code then add the class `submitme` to the input field you want the form to submit on when the enter key is pressed - this will call the `submitform()` method

Comment: I added the jquery and the class in my submit button but still pressing the enter button does not submit the form